# How do I force a ExecutorService.awaitTermination() timeout?

Tags: java, junit, concurrency

The code-under-test executes a set of `Callable` objects via  `ExecutorService.invokeAll()`.  The `ExecutorService` thread pool is then `shutdown()` and `awaitTermination()` is called.

```
ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(healthChecks.size());
List<Future <HealthStatus> > checkResults = threadpool.invokeAll(healthChecks);
threadpool.shutdown();

// Now wait for all the threads to finish as part of the shutdown.
if (!threadpool.awaitTermination(STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
{
    throw new Exception("Health checks did not all complete in time.");
}
```

I want to unit test an `awaitTermination()` timeout.

Now, I can inject my own set of `Callable` objects to run and so I created one that all by itself will cause the timeout.   That the class for that object looks like this (using a `ConcurrentUnit.Waiter` object):

```
public static final class TimeoutHealthCheck implements HealthChecker
{
    public final long SleepIntervalMillis;
    String healthName;
    boolean result;
    Waiter waiter;

    public TimeoutHealthCheck(long timeoutInMillis, boolean result, String healthName, Waiter waiter) {
        SleepIntervalMillis = timeoutInMillis;
        this.healthName = healthName;
        this.result = result;
        this.waiter = waiter;
    }
    public HealthStatus call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(SleepIntervalMillis);
        if (waiter != null) {
            waiter.resume();
        }
        return new TestHealthStatus(healthName,result);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the JUnit test it completes immediately (and I cannot confirm that the timeout path is taken in the code-under-test).

```
    @Test(expected = java.lang.Exception.class)
public void testStatusTimeout() throws Exception {

    final Waiter waiter = new Waiter();

    HealthChecker checker = new TimeoutHealthCheck(
            ServerStatusCheck.STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS*1000*2,
            true,
            "testStatusTimeout",
            waiter);

    Collection<HealthChecker> testCollect = new ArrayList<HealthChecker>(1);
    testCollect.add(checker);

    ServerStatusCheck checkUnderTest =
            new ServerStatusCheck(testCollect, new DefaultDateTimeProvider());

    checkUnderTest.Status();
    waiter.await(ServerStatusCheck.STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS*1000*3);
}
```

I am already using the `ConcurrentUnit` Maven package (0.4.1) but either I am misunderstanding what the Waiter does or it just isn't the right direction.

If it matters, I am running JUnit under Eclipse and with Java 8.

Comment: Post some relevant code so we can examine what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Fair enough.  I have added the code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use dependency injection ?

Comment: Yes,  I am using dependency injection.